# how to fetch URL in server and database dynamically on basis of name on click in table row in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

in reactjs how to fetch URL in server and database on basis of name  on click in table row in react js. At what i am trying to do is in my below code using react js, i have one table ok and  on the basis  of on-click table row name then url is open dynamically which is fetched in server or database .how can we do that.

right now in my code i fetch the url on-click row table statically but i want the fetch URL dynamically on the basis of name match. How can we do that.

suppose i have 10 different url in server.and i have one table row and column and when i click on one row then fetch one url on the basis of name.

is there any help. its very thankful.

```
var TableComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // Data
    var dataColumns = this.props.data.columns;
    var dataRows = this.props.data.rows;

    var tableHeaders = (<thead>
          <tr>
            {dataColumns.map(function(column) {
              return <th>{column}</th>; })}
          </tr>
      </thead>);

 var tableBody = dataRows.map(function(row) {
  return (
    <tr>
      {dataColumns.map(function(column) {
        return <td><a  target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={row.url}>{row[column]}</a></td>; })}
    </tr>); });
     
    // Decorate with Bootstrap CSS
    return (<table className="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        {tableHeaders}
        {tableBody}
      </table>) }});
        

// Example Data
var tableData = {
 columns: ['Service_Name', 'Cost/Unit', 'Unit', 'Units Requested'],
  rows: [{
    'Service_Name': 'one Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12,
    'url': 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blue.png',
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'two Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12,
    'url': 'http://codeskulptor-assets.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/assets_clock_background.png'
  },{
    'Service_Name': 'three Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
     'Units Requested': 12,
    'url': 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blend.png'
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'four Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'five Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'six Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'seven Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'eight Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'nine Assitance',
    'Cost/Unit': 50,
    'Unit': '1 Hour',
    'Units Requested': 12
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'ten',
    'Unit': null,
    'Cost/Unit': undefined,
    'Units Requested': 42
  }]
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <TableComponent data = {tableData} />,
  document.getElementById('table-component'));
```

Comment: plz anybody help me out this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @trixn i have doubt suppose i have 10 different url in server.and i have four button in page when i click on one button then fetch one url which i need.

Comment: like that i have 4 button in page red,green,blue,black button when i click red button then fetch one red url in server which i need fetch url.how can we do that using react in api or like database any idea????

Comment: I understood the problem. I'm asking for your attempted solution. What did you try so far?

Comment: Your question is too broadly scoped. You would need a complete tutorial on how to handle click events, how to use `fetch`, how to handle the response, how to render the response and so on. So I'm asking you: What did you try to solve the problem on your own and what exactly is it that you don't know how to do? Stack overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: thanks for reply . first of all i m asking how can we do that like that functionality in reactjs using api call or database ??.actually i m new in this that why

Comment: This site intends to answer specific narrowly scoped programming related questions that have a definitive answer. From what I can see you would need a whole tutorial on how to do a few very general things. There are plenty of great tutorials that explain that in length.